# If-then statement to filter rows within data flow task

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl

I using a data flow task to transfer data. I am looking to filter rows using the following if-then logic: it checks if the string starts which a certain value `310` and then I want to remove that entire row so that it does not show any row for which it had a string value of `310`. As example:

```
If objProf.CompCenter.toString().StartsWith("310") Then
    //Ignore Row
```

So in this case, if the column `CompCenter` contains a `310`, I would want the entire row to be removed. I'm not sure how to go about this after the then because I have to delete the list from the entire row.

Comment: What does this have to do with anything you've tagged here apart from C#? If this data is coming from SQL Server, why not use a `WHERE`?

Comment: @Larnu with his current edit, it's not even C#!

Comment: @Obaid what .NET language ARE you using? Please tag only the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

### SSIS Solution

*Since the question is tagged with [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis), then I will give a solution related to this tag.*

You should use a **conditional split** within the data flow task to filter rows based on a specific expression.

If you are looking to search if `CompCenter` startswith `310`, use a similar expression:

```
FINSTRING([CompCenter],"310",1) == 1
```

If you are looking to search if `CompCenter` contains `310`, use a similar expression:

```
FINSTRING([CompCenter],"310",1) > 0
```

For additional information about conditional split, you can refer to:

- [SSIS Conditional Split Transformation overview](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-conditional-split-transform-overview/)
- [SSIS Conditional Split overview](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-conditional-split-overview/)

---

### SQL Solution

If you are reading the data from an SQL database, you can filter rows using WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE [CompCenter] NOT LIKE '310%'
```

Comment: and a delete command would be similar DELETE FROM Table
WHERE [CompCenter] NOT LIKE '310%'

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD In delete command, you have to use `DELETE FROM Table WHERE [CompCenter] LIKE '310%'`

Comment: Okay.  You are right.  Unfortunately, it looks like this question is no longer tagged SSIS.  Wish they wouldn't close questions so quickly.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I edited an re-tagged the question, an voted to reopen it